# I am trying to add a line to the end of a concatinated txt file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which sets up a text file from several different files created from a database.  The command that I use to create the file is:

```
type %1 >>c:\atc\temp2\gamefishparks\sendgfp.xml
```

`%1` is a series of files generated from a database.  The output looks like this

```
         <Result>
         <GFPCaseID>  </GFPCaseID>
         <LabNumber>  </LabNumber>
         <ReceivedDate>    </ReceivedDate>
         <Pathologist>  </Pathologist>
         <ServiceArea></ServiceArea>
         <ProcedureName>: </ProcedureName>
         <TestName>: 
         <SpecNum></SpecNum>
         <Specimen></Specimen>
         <CompleteDate></CompleteDate>
         <Interpretation></Interpretation>
         <Organism></Organism>
         <NumericValue>  </NumericValue>
          </Result>
etc.
```

What I need at the end of this file essentially a footer.

At present I am using a text file named `footer.txt` and the command I am using is.

```
echo %1 %2 >>c:\atc\temp2\argname.txt
@(type %1; 
type "c:\atc\client\footergf.txt") >>"c:\atc\temp2\gamefishparks\sendgfp.xml"
set today=%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%
copy c:\atc\temp2\gamefishparks\sendgfp.xml c:\atc\temp2\gamefishparks\sent\%today%sent.xml
```

The problem is, it puts the footer in after every file the `%1` counter adds to the final file. What I need is for that footer to be at the end of the final file after all of the other files are added in.

any thoughts?

Comment: Is this really for DOS, and if so, which version. If this is for running within Windows instead, please [edit] your question to remove the [[tag:dos]] tag. There is a description for each tag that you use, if you are unsure whether it is suitable for the audiences to whom you are pitching your question. Also here if you want us to help you to fix a specific issue with your batch file, we expect a [mcve] of your batch file content, formatted within a code box, all output and relevant debugging information. Please make those improvements when you edit your tag, in order to receive assistance.

Comment: Batch file line 1: `@(type %1`; batch file line 2: `type "c:\atc\client\footergf.txt")>"c:\atc\temp2\gamefishparks\sendgfp.xml"`.

Comment: thanks Compo.  that almost works but the output i get is in this format  <First File><footer><second file><footer>...  what i need for output is <first file><second file><third file>.....<footer>     sorry about the format of this comment but i am unfamilliar with this forum.  every time i hit the enter key it would post my comment

Comment: We need you to show us exactly what the content of `%1` and `%2` is. That should be easily visible by including within your question post, the output from your first line: `echo %1 %2 >>c:\atc\temp2\argname.txt`. It would also help us greatly if you were also to explain exactly how you are passing those arguments to the batch file too. Also what you've posted does not match what I commented either!

Comment: here is the updated code with your suggested change.  I cant really give you specific information as to what is in the files that reflect %1 and %2 because of confidentiality but here is the output to the arguement file.  that i can give you.  %1 is the filename generated by the database query and %2 is the case number for associated with the file name in %1 the argument contents are this ``` c:\atc\temp\5556.txt 21GFP20212 ```

Comment: darren, the semi-colon wasn't part of the 'fenced' code I posted, it was part of the grammar of my comment. As for the your comment above, if you are only passing one file as `%1`, then of course the footer will be appended after each file has been `type`d! How is your batch file supposed to know when you've passed your final filename to it before deciding automagically when to add the footer?

Comment: that is the big question for me too. i tried to get around it by creating a second batch file than just sent the footer to the final file but even that ran after each file submission.  I can wait until after the file is created and run the footer batch file manually and that does work but that kind of defeats the purpose of trying to run the script automatically every night.

Comment: unless you tell us exactly how your batch file is being invoked then it is impossible for us to offer a solution. If you have a third party script or executable utility calling the batch file then you need to give us all of those details. If you believe that providing those details has to remain confidential then you are both wrong and out of luck.